# Python Decorator Nightmare

Tags: python-3.x

```
class viewer:

    def setup(func):
        func()

    def draw(func):
        func()

@viewer.setup
def set():
    x = 2017

@viewer.draw
def draw():
    print(x)
```

The code above results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    @viewer.draw
  File "test.py", line 7, in draw
    func()
  File "test.py", line 15, in draw
    print(x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

My question is, how can I implement the viewer such that the variables defined in setup are accessible in draw??

Comment: Well `x` is simply not in the scope of `draw`.

Comment: My question is, how can I implement the viewer such that the variables defined in setup are accessible in draw??

Answer (score 0):

An idea - but it is a **bad** idea, is to define a global variable:

```
x = None
class viewer:

    def setup(func):
        func()

    def draw(func):
        func()

@viewer.setup
def set():
    global x
    x = 2017

@viewer.draw
def draw():
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must (ideally) pass an object inside the function `set` that binds the attribute to it if you want to access it afterwards, at least, that's what I see you're going for.

Also, all your methods are missing the `self` argument which is probably not what you wanted. Despite that, you also use `<viewer_class>.set` instead of `.set.

Either work with an instance and pass `self` around:

```
class viewer:

    def setup(self, func):
        func(self)

    def draw(self, func):
        func(self)

# make an instance
view = viewer()

@view.setup
def set(obj):
    obj.x = 2017

@view.draw
def draw(obj):
    print(obj.x)
```

Or, make the methods `classmethods` and pass the class around:

```
class viewer:

    @classmethod
    def setup(cls, func):
        func(cls)

    @classmethod
    def draw(cls, func):
        func(cls)

view = viewer()

@viewer.setup
def set(obj):
    obj.x = 2017

@viewer.draw
def draw(obj):
    print(obj.x)
```